# Hibernate bi-directional one-to-one with composite key class using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, one-to-one, composite-primary-key

I'm having trouble getting my head arround this. 
How can I create an one-to-one bidirectional mapping between Organisation and OrganisationAddress? This is what I've tried so far:

I got two tables:

```
**ORGANISATION**
ORGNO <pk>
BANKNO <pk>

**ORGANISATION_ADDRESS**
ORGNO <pk, fk>
BANKNO <pk, fk>
```

A Java composite key class for each table:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrganisationPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="ORGNO", length=9)
    private String orgno;

    @Column(name="BANKNO", length=4)
    private String bankno;

    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class OrganisationAddressPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="ORGNO", length=9)
    private String orgno;

    @Column(name="BANKNO", length=4)
    private String bankno;

    ... getters/setters ...
}
```

This is the Java classes for Organisation and OrganisationAddress:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORGANISATION")
public class Organisation implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private OrganisationPK comp_id;

    /** bi-directional one-to-one association to OrganisationAddress */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "organisation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private OrganisationAddress organisationAddress;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORGANISATION_ADDRESS")
public class OrganisationAddress implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "orgno", column=@Column(name="ORGNO")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "bankno", column=@Column(name="BANKNO"))
    })
    private OrganisationAddressPK comp_id;

    /** bi-directional one-to-one association to Organisation */
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ORGNO", referencedColumnName = "ORGNO"),
            @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "BANKNO", referencedColumnName = "BANKNO")
    })
    private Organisation organisation;
```

When I run the tests, it gives me this error:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class org.hibernate.OrganisationAddress.
>
> Expected: class org.hibernate.OrganisationAddressPK, got class org.hibernate.OrganisationPK

From this call:

```
private void deleteOrganisation(Organisation organisation){
    Organisation hibOrganisation = (Organisation) getCurrentSession().get(
        Organisation.class, new OrganisationPK(
            organisation.getOrgNo(), BANKNO.getValue()));
...
```

Comment: Can you not use OrganisationPK in OrganisationAddress? OrganisationPK  and OrganisationAddressPK use the same columns to form the key anyway. Hibernate probably uses the first class that matches the column combination. You could use a generic name for the key for clarity.

Comment: OrganisationPK and OrganisationAddressPK are completely different except for the primary keys, so I'd like to keep them both. I found this link however, so I'll try this approach tomorrow. http://beavercreekconsulting.com/blog/2008/10/hibernate-annotations-for-a-one-to-many-mapping/
Only downside is that they use One-to-Many.